# how to set bootstrap nav tab active depending on database value in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using **bootstrap** styling for nav tabs in form, I want to **set the active tab** depending on the **value fetched** from database in edit screen. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li class="<%= 'active' if @model.some_value == 'value' %>" > 
      <%= link_to 'A', "#" %> 
   </li> 
</ul>
```